# gcc linker script difference between *(.rodata*) and *(.rodata.*)

Tags: gcc, linker

We have a linker script where a part of the .text section has the read only data input section specified as:

```
.text:
{
    ...
    *(.rodata .rodata* .gnu.linkonce.r.*)
    ...
}
```

However, other input sections that have a trailing wildcard usually have a `.` between name and wildcard. Like: `*(.text .text.* .gnu.linkonce.t.*)`

Is there a difference in how the linker treats `.`'s and wildcard combinations or is there no difference?

Should the `.rodata*` actually be `.rodata.*`?

Comment: List the sections of a few object files and see if there's any `.rodata.*` section. If there isn't then the script is probably alright.

Comment: Yeah, @Someprogrammerdude is right. If you have assembly code, you might have arbitrarily named sections. So you'd have to wade through _all_ of your object files in all build scenarios and make sure all `.rodata` section names are followed by `.`. And `.` here is just a dot, not a regexp special character; you realize this, don't you? (Yes, there _is_ a difference.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.text*` is simply shorter than the more explicit `.text .text.*`, though not equivalent. It would pick up other sections like `.text_foo`. This can be intended (to make it more independent of the compiler convention maybe?) or not.

https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Input-Section-Wildcards.html

The `.*` sections are generated by gcc if you pass `-ffunction-sections`. The same holds for data and `-fdata-sections`.